# Identity ApplicationDbContext with ninject

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

I am using ninject for my entities and have created a custom dbcontext, which holds my poco classes. This is **CusDbContext** . I then add *this to identity by adding it as a parameter in the base class constructor for **ApplicationDbContext**

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("CusDbContext", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
    }
```

So now in my webconfig the connection string is set to CusDbContext. This all works fine. On the initial create *( when i register a user and .net creates the db in background with all the user tables )*
**This database is local by the way (local)\v11.0**

The tables are created and the user is added and all works fine. Then when i add migrations for code first it states

> More than one context type was found in the assembly

Cool so i use my **CusDbContext**.

```
PM>Enable-Migrations -ContextTypeName Library.Data.Concrete.CusDbContext
PM>Add-Migration init
```

And i get the error

> Library.Data.Concrete.IdentityUserLogin: : EntityType
>   'IdentityUserLogin' has no key defined. Define the key for this
>   EntityType.

That is a viewModel though (O.o)

Why is the migration trying to add a viewmodel as an entity? Is there any way to have one context type using identities default files? I still want to use ninject.

Comment: Can you prove that you don't have in `ApplicationDbContext` an `DbSet<IdentityUserLogin>`?

Comment: @adricadar I am not to sure how to do that. IdentityUserLogin is in the AccountViewModel class file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
```

This was needed on the ApplicationDbContext in order to build.